# When 2 \newpages in raw are joined, and when not?

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, titlesec

I tried to define my `chapter` so it will have an empty page after it, using `titlesec`. Using 2 `newpage`s in a raw didn't help. I concluded that they are joined together, as if I wrote only 1. Solved this by adding `\null` between them.

Then, I defined my `section` to begin on a new page, expecting that in case  it's the first thing after the chapter, the section's `newpage` will be joined with the chapter's second `newpage`.

However, I got 2 empty pages between the chapter and section, instead of 1.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\huge}{}{0.5ex}
{
 % before-code
\centering
}
[
 % after-code
\newpage
\null
\newpage
] 

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large}{}{0.5ex} 
{
 % before-code
      \newpage
      \centering
}
[ % after-code
] 

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius nisl sed enim consectetur, eu tempor libero cursus. Nulla at enim nunc. Duis vitae nibh erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eget ornare velit. Ut porta sed libero non tincidunt. Mauris dapibus pulvinar ornare.
\section{Second section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius nisl sed enim consectetur, eu tempor libero cursus. Nulla at enim nunc. Duis vitae nibh erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eget ornare velit. Ut porta sed libero non tincidunt. Mauris dapibus pulvinar ornare.
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: If there is nothing in the page, \newpage does nothing.  \null, while invisible, counts as something  \strut \hbox{} \rule{0pt}{0pr} are all invisible but take up space..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want each section to start on a new page, here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\huge}
  {}
  {0.5ex}
  {\centering}
  [\cleardoublepage]

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\clearpage\large}
  {}
  {0.5ex}
  {\centering}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius nisl
sed enim consectetur, eu tempor libero cursus. Nulla at enim nunc. Duis
vitae nibh erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eget ornare velit. Ut porta sed libero
non tincidunt. Mauris dapibus pulvinar ornare.

\section{Second section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius nisl
sed enim consectetur, eu tempor libero cursus. Nulla at enim nunc. Duis
vitae nibh erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eget ornare velit. Ut porta sed libero
non tincidunt. Mauris dapibus pulvinar ornare.

\end{document}
```

You had the `\newpage` (but `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` are generally better) in the wrong place in the format for `\section`.

Comment: That's working, but I still don't understand... Why putting the `\clearpage` in `before-code` is wrong, while putting it in `format` is working?

Comment: @Zvika In the `<before code>` only “paragraph mode” text is expected.